# How to extract two integers from unknown indexes from a string

Tags: java, string, int

Very simple question - I have a string that looks like `PR:MTH 1 MTR 7`. I want to extract the numbers in that string to integer variables.

The problem is that I don't know how many digits these integers have. for example `PR:MTH 100000 MTR 777` is also a valid string. So I can't specify the exact indexes where the numbers are.

All we can say for sure is that the MSB of the first number is at index 7 (I counted).

Is there some String method or StringBuilder method in java that does this? or do I need to write one of my own?

Comment: `String.split("[ :]")[indexOfInteger]`

Comment: try to do sub string with regular expression

Answer (score 3):

[`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) is your friend in this situation

Split the string with spaces and colons and parse the corresponding indexes.

```
String s = "PR:MTH 100000 MTR 777";
String[] split = s.split("[ :]");
int one = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
int two = Integer.parseInt(split[4]);
```

Comment: Thank you! very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you should try split(" ") and then take values u need and convert to integer

Comment: Thank you! very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `yourString.split(" ");` and iterate that array searching for all the numbers, using a try-catch block. In order to save them, you can use an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

I would do something like:

```
    String myString = "dsfsd 12 12 dd";
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] splitString = myString.split(" ");

    for (String split : splitString) {
        try {
            numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(split));
        } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
            //not a number
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("I have %d numbers in my String! \n", numbers.size());
```

In order to obtain the numbers, you just need to iterate the `ArrayList`.

```
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        //your code
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the general case, use regex to find the numbers:

```
String number1 = str.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d+).*", "$1");
String number2 = str.replaceAll("\\D*\\d+\\D+(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

This has the advantage of working with input that doesn't have a clear delimiter, eg if the input string was

```
foo123bar456baz
```

the above code would successfully extract `123` and `456`.